# C terminology: header vs. signature

Tags: c, terminology

the word header as far as I know is usually in reference to a header file while the word signature is in reference to the arguments and return type of the function. For example, in my experience this would be called a signature:

```
int ptInPoly(Point q, Point p[], int n)
```

My professor is calling this a header in my assignments. I have found this confusing and would like to know if this different use terminology is common or something that only he does. Thanks

Here is some more context around the use of the term header:

"Your program must have a function with header: `int ptInPoly(Point q, Point p[], int n)` that determines if point q is in the polygon given in p"

Comment: Yeah, the assignment is just using the wrong terminology.

Comment: Your professor isn't the only one using that terminology, but it's still wrong. You'll see it on forums and terrible sites like tutorialspoint.

Comment: Your professor is correct, until the end of the term ;)

Comment: of course he's correct in that sense, i'm just interested in what is considered correct and in correct terminology wise

Comment: Actually, it is neither: in C, this is called a _prototype_.

Comment: I would say that _function header_ would be a nice term, when indicating the line(s) that introduces the function body.

Answer (score 3):

The correct term is *function declaration*. When the parameter types are spelled out explicitly, as in your case `int ptInPoly(Point q, Point p[], int n);` it can also be called a *function prototype*. (Non-prototype format is considered very bad practice and rarely used nowadays.) A function prototype is a function declaration.

Function declaration and function prototype are formal terms used by the C standard.

The meaning of *header* is indeed a header file, with `.h` as extension. The C standard uses the term header to describe header files.

So your professor is using the wrong terminology.

Comment: Actually, the C standard doesn't say anything about headers being files. Instead it calls the ones included with `#include <foo.h>` as being headers, but it is not stated anywhere that they need to be files at all.

Comment: I just read the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.2p2) :D `-pedantic`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ok, please get back to me when you find a C tool chain which doesn't use files, but other... things.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala What about paragraph 1 on the same section: *"A #include directive shall identify a header or source **file** that can be processed by the
implementation."*

Comment: @Lundin: There were several self-hosted C compilers that ran on the Palm pilot. Since PalmOS did not have a filesystem (it only had a relational database) the toolchain had to store and read source from tables

Comment: @user694733 that applies to the `#include "foo.h"` specifically :) but it allows the compiler to for example contain the header embedded to it. Anyway, what I am saying is that the standard calls the ones that can be included with `<foo.h>` as headers, and the ones that can be only included with `"foo.h"` source files; and that `"foo.h"` search falls back to header search.

Comment: also, [footnote 182](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note182): A header is not necessarily a source file, nor are the < and > delimited sequences in header names necessarily valid source file names.

Answer (score 3):

Header is never a correct term for this. The C11 standard explicitly defines that a ***header*** is that which is included in the form [`#include <foo.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.2p2); here `<foo.h>` is a name of a *header*. Thus `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>` and such are headers. (They need not be actual files though, nor in C source code: [C11 footnote 182](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note182)):

> 182) A header is not necessarily a source file, nor are the < and > delimited sequences in header names necessarily valid source file names.

---

Signature, on the other hand, is somewhat better, if not very exact, as it is not the one used by the standard. The standard uses the term ***prototype*** for a declaration of a function signature that specifies the types of the parameters. [(C11 6.2.1p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.1p2):

> [...] A function prototype is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters. [...]

Why a signature is somewhat vague is because in C a function need not have a prototype, but such a function could still considered having a partial signature, but is not a [type signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) in the strictest sense. Additionally, prototypeless declarations are considered ***obsolescent*** in C99 and C11 [(C11 6.11.6, 6.11.7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.6):

> 6.11.6 Function declarators
>
> 1 The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.
>
> 6.11.7 Function definitions
>
> 1 The use of function definitions with separate parameter identifier and declaration lists (not prototype-format parameter type and identifier declarators) is an obsolescent feature.

---

Thus the best wording would be

> Your program must have a function with **prototype** `int ptInPoly(Point q, Point p[], int n)` that determines if point `q` is in the polygon given in `p`"

Comment: Non-prototype functions have even been flagged as obsolescent since C99.

Comment: @Lundin True, but I consider C99 obsolescent :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I understood that this

```
int ptInPoly(Point q, Point p[], int n)
```

is a header, but this

```
 ptInPoly(Point q, Point p[], int n)
```

is called signature. it is given a different name because in ***function overloading*** the signature of the function(**function name + parameter list**) is important.